# Reiniciar um programa em Python com Input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte programa abaixo em Python com 2 funções, uma para converter reais em dolares de acordo com a cotação, e uma para converter de dolares para reais também de acordo com a cotação, além de um simples menu para decidir entre as 2 funções:

```
def reaispdolar () :
  Reais = float (input("Quantos reais? R$: "))
  Cotação = float (input("Cotação de hoje é? "))
  conversão = Reais/Cotação
  print("Você possui US$" , ("%.2f" % conversão))


def dolarpreais () :
  Dolar = float(input("Quantos Dolares? US$: "))
  Cotação = float(input("Cotação de hoje é? "))
  Conversão = Cotação*Dolar
  print("Você possui: R$", ("%.2f" % Conversão))

print("O que deseja fazer? ")
print("1 - Converter reais em dolares")
print("2 - Converter dolares em reais")
menu = input("Deseje a opção desejada\n")
if menu == "1" :
    reaispdolar()
elif menu == "2" :
  dolarpreais()
else : 
    print("Valor inválido",)
```

O que eu gostaria é que, no menu, sendo o `input` inválido ou quando o `input` for correto e a conversão der seu valor final, a seguinte mensagem aparece: "Deseja reiniciar S/N ?": ").

E quando o usuário pressiona "S" ou "s" o programa volta ao "menu iniciar". É possível fazer isso sem `while`?

Comment: `while` não é uma metodologia é instrução de laço de repetição  e um programador que tem medo de usar um laço é futuro tiozinho da pipoca. Ps: Nada contra os tiozinhos da pipoca, mas não acredito que alguém tenha cursado uma faculdade para virar pipoqueiro.

Comment: @Augusto Vasques -> Em que momento alguem citou medo de usar ? Entendo que While é importante e pode ser usado nesse caso, a unica coisa sobre a qual a minha pergunta trata é sobre outras maneiras de realizar a mesma operação sem o while. Sem cabimento seu comentário.

Comment: Conseguiu uma resposta. Mas será que ela lhe é mais benéfica? Ou para quem está iniciando carreira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível continuar no programa sem utilizar um `while` ou `for`, uma forma é utilizando a **[recursão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))**.

Você pode criar uma função que terá como corpo o seu menu atual:

```
def opcoes():
  print("O que deseja fazer? ")
  print("1 - Converter reais em dolares")
  print("2 - Converter dolares em reais")
  menu = input("Deseje a opção desejada\n")
  if menu == "1" :
    reaispdolar()
  elif menu == "2" :
    dolarpreais()
  else : 
    print("Valor inválido")
```

Agora seu código terá três funções, com isso você chamará a função `opcoes` logo após as declarações das funções, inicializando assim seu programa:

```
opcoes()
```

Para criar a recursão, sua função `opcoes`, deve chamar ela mesma:

```
def opcoes():
  print("O que deseja fazer? ")
  print("1 - Converter reais em dolares")
  print("2 - Converter dolares em reais")
  menu = input("Deseje a opção desejada\n")
  if menu == "1" :
    reaispdolar()
  elif menu == "2" :
    dolarpreais()
  else : 
    print("Valor inválido")

  opcoes()
```

Com isso, você terá o seu programa em constante execução. Porém existe um problema, seu programa está em um loop infinito, portanto é sempre importante pensar em uma condição que finalizará a recursão, que no caso, é a pergunta ao usuário se ele deseja reiniciar:

```
def opcoes () :
  print("O que deseja fazer? ")
  print("1 - Converter reais em dolares")
  print("2 - Converter dolares em reais")
  print("3 - Encerrar o programa")

  menu = input("Deseje a opção desejada\n")

  if menu == "1" :
    reaispdolar()
  elif menu == "2" :
    dolarpreais()
  else : 
    print("Valor inválido",)  

  reinicia = input("Deseja reiniciar S/N ?").upper()

 if reinicia == "S" :
   opcoes()
```

Pronto, agora existe a possibilidade de sair da recursão e finalizar o programa.

---

> Veja o código completo online: https://repl.it/repls/ParchedGummyServerapplication

Comment: descobri que uso recursão e nem sabia!

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*[A outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/438534/112052) sugere usar recursão, que é uma forma de fazer sem `while`, mas não é o melhor jeito, porque se o usuário ficar no loop várias vezes, as chamadas recursivas vão se acumulando e isso pode causar um estouro de pilha ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/CF4tgc) um exemplo, role até o final da página e veja o [`RecursionError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError)). Já usando `while`, não há esse problema. Só porque é possível fazer algo, não quer dizer que você deva fazê-lo.*</sup>

---

Por que não quer usar `while`? Além de ser uma das estruturas mais básicas da programação, é a forma mais simples. Basta fazer um *loop* e só interrompê-lo quando a opção não for "S" ou "s":

```
while True:
    print("O que deseja fazer? ")
    print("1 - Converter reais em dolares")
    print("2 - Converter dolares em reais")
    menu = input("Deseje a opção desejada\n")
    if menu == "1" :
        reaispdolar()
    elif menu == "2" :
      dolarpreais()
    else: 
        print("Valor inválido")
    if input('Deseja reiniciar (S/N)? ') not in ('S', 's'):
        break # se digitar qualquer coisa diferente de "s" ou "S", sai do loop
```

No caso, eu verifico se a opção digitada não foi "S" nem "s" (ou seja, se a pessoa digitar qualquer coisa diferente - não necessariamente "N"), ele sai do programa.

Claro que dá para sofisticar mais, por exemplo, verificando se a opção é mesmo "S" ou "N" (e rejeitando qualquer outra coisa):

```
while True:
    print("O que deseja fazer? ")
    print("1 - Converter reais em dolares")
    print("2 - Converter dolares em reais")
    menu = input("Deseje a opção desejada\n")
    if menu == "1" :
        reaispdolar()
    elif menu == "2" :
      dolarpreais()
    else: 
        print("Valor inválido",)
    while True:
        opcao = input('Deseja reiniciar (S/N)? ').lower() # converter para minúsculo
        if opcao not in ('s', 'n'):
            print('opcao invalida, deve ser S ou N')
        else: break # sai do while interno, pois a opção é S ou N
    if opcao == 'n': break # se for N, sai do loop externo
```

Mas a ideia geral é essa: use `break` para sair do *loop*, e só chame o `break` se a condição de saída for satisfeita.

Comment: Para quem deu o negativo, considere o comentário que coloquei depois da edição sobre o uso de recursão. Só porque o AP pediu sem while, não quer dizer que seja a melhor maneira, e eu não vou sugerir recursão em um caso no qual claramente é a pior solução

Comment: Concordo contigo sobre não utilizar recursão, como ele citou sem while, acreditei com a solução com while ele já deveria ter conhecimento, respondi com o exemplo, assim ele conhece a possibilidade de recursão e também os problemas que ela pode trazer.

Comment: Agradeço a hkotsubo e DanielMendes pelos esclarecimentos. Entendo que o while seja a melhor opção e agradeço terem demonstrado o exemplo. Agradeço também o exemplo usando recursão, agora que sei os dois e o risco de cada um, posso escolher melhor conforme o problema ou projeto. Obrigado ao dois!

Comment: @YagoFdev Na verdade `while` não tem "riscos" nesse caso, é a opção segura sem contra-indicações :-)  De qualquer forma, se vc achou as respostas úteis, pode [votar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) nelas. Além disso, também pode escolher a que melhor resolveu sua dúvida (apenas uma delas) e aceitá-la - [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema